# How to know what type of arguments a built in function take via something like dir()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, hashmap

I want to know if there is a way to know what kind of arguments (also how many)  a method can take. For example in below code I know I can do `dir(d)` to get a **list of all methods** for that dictionary, but is there a way where I can say like `somekeyword(d.keys())` and it will provide output of **datatypes/arguments** which keys method can take:

`input = dir(d.keys())`, and `output = keys( arg1,arg2,arg3 .... )` 
(with type of arguments)

```
d = {} 
dir (d) 
['__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__delitem__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'fromkeys',
 'get',
 'items',
 'keys',
 'pop',
 'popitem',
 'setdefault',
 'update',
 'values']
```

Comment: If function is in `builtins` you want to read `help(func)` I think.

Comment: @sashaaero thats cool thanks a lot 
i ran this one ---> ```help (d.fromkeys('k'))```
this gave me a lot of information  about dictionary class it self however it also provided the code where i am    able  to find which  arguments the function is taking.